# Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo C260: horrible graphics/system performance

Tags: 16.04, graphics, xorg, performance

I have a couple Lenovo C260 all-in-one PCs that I was able to get working with Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit (Desktop) about two years ago.  Then Google decided to stop supporting Chrome on 32-bit Linux.  I was able to install Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on one of the three machines, but failed on the other two.  And the one that worked was not stable (occasional crashes, fails to shutdown or reboot via software).

I have managed to get one of the other machines working, but only barely.  I installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server (which does not hang or show any kind of performance problem).  I made sure I got all the updates.  I then manually installed the desktop packages.

When I boot, I can get the login screen for 5 seconds to 5 minutes and then the machine appears to hang completely.  Sometimes I can login completely and bring up a terminal window before the machine hangs.  The drive light is stuck on when it hangs.

In searching around I found a page that indicated that the graphics driver was using kernel mode setting and to try booting the kernel with "nomodeset".  I did that.

Success!  Sort of.

The system is almost unusable.  Compiz takes between 10 and 150% of the CPU (which is an Intel Celeron J1800 at 2.4GHz).  Hitting a key causes a CPU spike.

Wireless keyboards and mice drop or repeat keystrokes all the time.  A wired keyboard and mouse mostly works but there is about .5 seconds of delay between hitting a key and seeing anything on the screen.  I still get some repeat keystrokes (usually more than 100x).

I tried loading the unity tweak tool and the compiz configuration tool and turning off all the effects I could find.  I still get high CPU load and dropped keystrokes and repeat keystrokes (that did not get any better).

Any suggestions of what to try next?  I am installing Lubuntu as I type this in the hope that a non-compiz-based GUI might be better.

Would a later kernel help with the drivers?  My understanding is that by using "nomodeset", I disable the kernel mode setting and thus X runs the graphics in VESA mode.

These systems were perfectly usable with Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

EDIT: Lubuntu did not help this.  The only thing that seems to help stability is turning off kernel mode setting.  Even with mode setting turned off, the system will not stay up more than a day or so at most.  Just now, I got a kernel panic which did not repeat on reboot.  I am starting to suspect that I got a few bad machines rather than anything really Linux specific.

EDIT 2: As noted below, I gave up.  I was unable to install 14.04 64-bit either.  Same kinds of problems though generally the system would last a little longer before hanging or crashing (generally it would just freeze).  One machine is still functional, the other two are not at all.

If I install just the server packages (no graphics), the systems are fine. Of course, that makes them a little hard to use as desktops.

I suspect that the graphics drivers are the main source of problems.  However, the EFI BIOS on these machines has a reputation of being pure cr*p.  You cannot adjust much at all.  Perhaps they are just lemons.

I purchased some ASUS 21.5" AIO machines and they work very very well.  Since these machines are the primary desktops for my mother's business, having all but one machine down was just not acceptable and we had to move forward.

Based on the three machines I have, I would strongly recommend against the Lenovo C260 machines.

Comment: Why were you using a 32-bit version on a 64-bit CPU? Have you tried the 64-bit version of 14.04?

Comment: I had carried over a much older system (upgraded from 10.04 originally).  That was on really old hardware, hence 32-bit.  None of the systems reliably shutdown with 10.04.

Comment: Oops, hit return too soon.  I had hoped that moving to 16.04 would be better as support for older hardware (this isn't that old) usually gets better with time.  In this case, it seems to have gone backwards, badly.

Comment: Your CPU is 64-bit. Try the 64-bit version of 14.04. 16.04 is still very new, not everything has been ported over yet.

Comment: I will try with 14.04 and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, still no good.  I was not even able to get it to install without hitting a hang or kernel panic.   Two of three machines do the same thing.  I am going to give up on this.  These machines are for my mother's business and I have already purchased some ASUS All-In-One machines that are much nicer and on which 16.04 installs and works flawlessly.  We just could not wait any more.  Thanks for the help.